# Is there a serialization format for PHP that I can seek without loading everything?

Tags: php, serialization

I have a huge array like this:

```
array(
  '5486215d2f02cc0f257ebda5125486215d2f02c' /* (SHA1) */ => array(
    'filename' => 'p_2486433.png',
    'directory' => 'aaaac2013'
  ),
  '95b23be7c97d532295b23be7c97d532295b23be' => array(
    'filename' => 'p_4857312.png',
    'directory' => 'aaaff2013'
  ),
  ...
)
```

Currently I store this as a JSON, which requires me to load the whole structure, a disadvantage it shares with `serialize()`.

Is there a common format that maintains some kind of index so I can seek to the entry I am looking for without loading the whole thing into memory?

Comment: That would be a database.

Comment: Yes, but if I look for "databases", stuff like MySQL and SQLite comes up. The kind of "database" I am looking for is more like the "db" databases that _postmap_ creates, but I don't know what that is and whether there is a PHP library for it.

Comment: Doesn't postmap create Berkeley DB? That's not far off from SQLite if you don't want something running as a service and talking TCP.

Comment: Turns out [there is a library for Berkeley DB](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dba.php) in PHP.

Comment: You could even do this with symbolic links in the filesystem!

Answer (score 0):

I see comments about creating file-based databases however if this doesn't work anyway you might take the larger file and break it into smaller pieces like one record per file and then group with a directory.

Of course there are drawbacks in doing this like flooding your filesystem with a lot of entries that might create some issues on the long run.